# How can I access Office 365 (Private) Groups using Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app, office-365

My company just started using [Office 365 Private Groups](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2017/04/18/introducing-groups-in-outlook-for-mac-ios-and-android/) instead of distribution lists.  While distribution lists worked fine in Mail.app, I can't seem to find any way to access Private Groups without using the Office 365 web portal.

Is there a way to access my Office 365 Private Groups from within Mail.app?

Comment: I can't say for sure, that's why I'm not adding it as an Answer, but I believe this is only available by using Outlook for Mac or Outlook for iOS.  As far as I know, MS doesn't have plans to offer this outside of Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way for the IMAP sync to work. My staff are using either the teams iOS app or Outlook iOS app to get at those group assets like files and mails. It’s not the same experience as using Apple’s apps and it is something you’ll want to use Microsoft user voice or your company’s  Microsoft technical account manager to advocate that they enable normal IMAP sync for those folders.

Comment: I dont really have the Private Groups set up on my system. Could you check [`telnet`ing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789687(v=exchg.80).aspx) to see if the folders are even listed? I wonder if it even appears.

Comment: Hi @Josh. To where would I telnet? Maybe explain in [chat] I’m comfortable using nmap to check open ports, but all the content Microsoft delivers is https afaik for Office 365 groups.